# Compiled autohotkey file does not run, uncompiled works

Tags: autohotkey

[image]

I'm getting started with autohotkey. I have the following script:

```
#NoEnv
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%
CoordMode, Mouse, Window
SendMode Input
#SingleInstance Force
SetTitleMatchMode 2
#WinActivateForce
SetControlDelay 1
SetWinDelay 0
SetKeyDelay -1
SetMouseDelay -1
SetBatchLines -1


F4::
Macro1:
WinMaximize,    xxx | Reporting
Sleep, 333
WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, Toggle,  xxx   | Reporting
Sleep, 333
WinActivate,  xxx   | Reporting
Sleep, 333
Sleep, 94
Click, -189, -85, 0
Control, Check, , WindowsForms10.BUTTON.app.0.26ac0ad_r9_ad16,   xxx  | Reporting
Control, Check, , WindowsForms10.Window.8.app.0.26ac0ad_r9_ad1199,   xxx  | Reporting
Return
```

When I doubleclick TEST3 script (which works uncompiled in Pullover's macro creator) and which I compiled using Ahk2Exe, I see it in the tray on my win 10 computer:

[image]

But it doesn't seem to do anything.  What am i doing wrong?

Comment: By using SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir% means you have to put in the same folder as your uncompiled script if you have not already done that.

Comment: I don't know how this is initiated in script form, but I do notice an unused label, `Macro1:`. Prehaps this was made use of in script form. Regardless, there is a hotkey associated with it, `F4`, have you tried pressing that while it's running?